# Items added to a global array variable do not persist outside of the adding function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Google maps JavaScript API to draw a line between two points. The two points need to be geocoded (transformed into google.maps.LatLong objects) before they can be used to draw a line.

The Geocoding function is codeAddress, and when it returns it calls the callback function that adds the new latlong to a global array called points. For some reason the values added to points do not persist outside of the array. I'm relatively new to JavaScript so I can't tell what might be wrong, any thoughts would be appreciated!

```
var points = new Array();

function addGeocodedLatLongToGlobalList(address) {
        points.push(address);
        alert("added a point " + points[0]); // correctly outputs latlong object
    }

function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address, }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            addGeocodedLatLongToGlobalList(results[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

function drawLine(address1, address2, color) {

    codeAddress(address1);
    codeAddress(address2);

    alert("there is a point " + points[0]);  //now the points[0] value is undefined
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're looking into the points array before the asychronous geocode function has completed and the points have actually been put into the array.

The `geocoder.geocode()` function is probably an asynchronous function and your calls to the codeAddress function only initiate that process and it completes some time later.  That would explain why the alert() in your `drawLine()` function doesn't see any points - they aren't there yet.  They will be put into the points array when the geoCode function actually completes and calls it's callback.

Comment: "asynchronous function" ... please don't confuse the beginner with non-existent terms... "asynchronous function" doesn't exist in javascript.

Comment: An asynchronous function is one that starts an operation when you call it, returns immediately and then finishes some time later, usually calling some sort of completion function when it is done.  Most ajax calls work this way.  It's not a property of the language (nor did I mean to imply so), but how most operations in a browser that use networking work.  As such, you can't use the results of the operation when the first function call returns because the operation is not yet complete.  You have to wait until the completion callback is called signifying that the operation is now done.

Comment: You explained the principle correctly and nicely, but I'd recommend not to use the term "asynchronous function", because it speaks about some type of function which doesn't exist in javascript. Don't define new terms. The "function" itself is not asynchronous. In certain cases we *might* call the whole operation "asynchronous", but also this might not be the case - I wouldn't call every callback passing as "asynchronous operation". It might be just a normal initialization of some event handling object.

Comment: But this operation appears to involve an ajax call (internal to the geocode() method) and thus the operation is likely asynchronous and the OP needs to understand that and what that means for their code.  What would you call a function that works that way?  I call it an "asynchronous function".

Comment: well, "(asynchronous) ajax call" sounds more clear to me (because it refers not only to the function, but to the whole operation itself).

Comment: Just for completeness here, there are other asynchronous operations besides those things that use ajax calls.  For example, animations involving timers are asynchronous.  You make a function call to start the animation, it returns immediately and completes some time later.

Comment: I have an open question similar to this OP. Is there a standard method of realizing when the the asynchronous operation is complete?

Comment: @josh - yes, you put your code in the completion function which is called when the async operation is done.

Comment: @jfriend I apologize. You may need to be more blunt with me. :) Completion function? Using the OP as an example, `.geocode` accepted data params, then the callback. Where would you be able execute a function that only executes once `.geocode` is complete?

Comment: @Josh - that's what the callback is for.  The callback function gets called when the asynchronous operation has completed.  You put your code in that callback.

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that the callback function you pass as 2nd parameter to `geocoder.geocode` has not been called yet. The geocoder might have just stored it for calling it later upon some event. Place some `alert` into the callback function to see if it was really called!

```
...
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address, }, function (results, status) {
        alert("CALLBACK CALLED!!");
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
...
```